# matplotlib is not displaying the plot but printing data after certain rows

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I want to plot the data using matplotlib,the data contains date and three different prices as columns.The plot is not getting displayed instead the values are getting printed after certain rows till last.At the last it is printing 'not found'.Here is my small csv sample:

```
2017-09-01 10:00:00,3072,,
2017-09-01 10:30:00,3074,,
2017-09-01 11:00:00,3072,,
2017-09-01 11:30:00,3072,,
2017-09-01 12:00:00,3066,,
2017-09-01 12:30:00,3062,,
2017-09-01 13:00:00,3064,,
2017-09-01 13:30:00,3066,,
2017-09-01 14:00:00,3063,,
2017-09-01 14:30:00,3063,,
2017-09-01 15:00:00,3060,,
2017-09-01 15:30:00,3063,,
2017-09-01 16:00:00,3063,,
2017-09-01 16:30:00,3071,48.57142857,
2017-09-01 17:00:00,3083,61.70212766,
2017-09-01 17:30:00,3075,50.94339623,
2017-09-01 18:00:00,3068,46.55172414,
2017-09-01 18:30:00,3072,50.0,
```

Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import datetime
import time
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as mticker
import matplotlib.dates as mdates


data=open('fin1.csv','r').read()
date,p1,p2,p3 = np.loadtxt(data,delimiter=',',unpack=True,converters={0:mdates.bytespdate2num("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")})

plt.plot(date,p1)
plt.plot(date,p2)
plt.plot(date,p3)


plt.show()
```

The last few lines of the output:

```
2017-09-29 18:30:00,3370,47.82608696,3376.0
2017-09-29 19:00:00,3369,47.31182796,3376.0
2017-09-29 19:30:00,3363,46.31578947,3375.35
2017-09-29 20:00:00,3372,47.42268041,3375.1
2017-09-29 20:30:00,3365,41.41414141,3374.5
2017-09-29 21:00:00,3365,35.55555556,3373.9
2017-09-29 21:30:00,3369,45.56962025,3373.65
2017-09-29 22:00:00,3382,52.22222222,3374.05
2017-09-29 22:30:00,3373,45.83333333,3374.2
 not found.
```

Comment: what does plt.get_backend() return?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the read() and use np.genfromtxt

```
data=open('fin1.csv','r')


date,p1,p2,p3 = np.genfromtxt(data,delimiter=',',unpack=True,converters={0:mdates.bytespdate2num("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")})
```

Answer (score 0):

You are currently doing a little bit too much. And use [`np.genfromtxt`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html) instead since it handles missing values which you have. Just use the function directly on the filename e.g.:

```
date,p1,p2,p3 = np.genfromtxt('fin1.csv',delimiter=',',unpack=True,
                              converters={0:mdates.bytespdate2num("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")})
```